# SQL how to sum rows from 2 tables but only use type of 1 table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like below

**Table 1**

```
ID    Title    Number
001   Student   10
002   Student   20
004   Teacher   25
```

**Table 2**

```
ID    Title       Number
001   Researcher   10
002   Student      20
004   Professor    25
```

I want to merge the 2 tables such that the number of the same ID are added together but the Title follows that of table 1, so an output like

```
ID    Title    Number
001   Student   20
002   Student   40
004   Teacher   50
```

Thanks.

Comment: And you have tried what so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Title, (t1.number + t2.number) as total 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.ID= t2.ID
```

Comment: This approach assumes that there are no duplicate IDs in either of the 2 tables.  I'm not saying you are wrong if this not be the case.

Comment: yup, but if there is duplicate id come its run with one to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to begin by doing a `UNION ALL` of the two tables, and computing the sum of the `Number` field, grouping on the `ID`.  This result can then be joined back to Table 1 again to use the `Title` field there.

```
SELECT t2.ID, t1.Title, t2.Number
FROM
Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.ID, SUM(t.Number) AS Number
    (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.Number
        FROM Table1 t1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t2.ID, t2.Number
        FROM Table2 t2
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.ID
) t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

select a.id,a.title,(a.number+b.number) as number from table1 as a INNER JOIN table2 as b on a.id=b.id;